# how to change binary to Decimal using bitwise operator?

Tags: python, binary, decimal, bitwise-operators

After I asked questions about this code (to find the resolution of an image),

```
with open("image.jpg",'rb') as file:
    file.seek(163)
    a = file.read(2)
    height = (a[0] << 8) | a[1]
    a = file.read(2)
    width = (a[0] << 8) | a[1]
print(str(height) + " x " + str(width))
```

I got a lot of answers which made me ask more questions. One of them is Can I change binary to decimal with bitwise operators?
Let me show you what I got and tell me if there are better ways.

```
a = 0b11       #which is 3 in decimal
b = a >> 2     #2 is the length of a
print(a | b)
print(b | a)

a = 0b1000000000 #which is 512 in decimal
b = a >> 10      #10 is the length of a
print(a | b)
print(b | a)
```

It works. Even if

```
a = 0b11
b = a >> 10000000000  
print(a | b)
```

Still the answers are the same.

Comment: The code is not changing binary to decimal.  The code is taking two bytes and making a Int16.   The bytes are high byte and then low byte.  So the code is shifting the first byte 8 bits and then OR'ing the LSB.   the following format is binary : a = 0b11  which is the same as a = 3.

Comment: Should I do more research about bitwise or just use PIL library?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code.  It is efficient.  I do not like using libraries for simple operations.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem** -> you're just printing the same number:

```
b = a >> 2
```

Here, when you're doing the `right shift` by `2`. It's actually converting `0b11` to `0b00`. The `bitwise OR` operation will then result in the same number i.e `0b11`.

Same, if true for:

```
b = a >> 10000000000
```

Here, you're doing the `right shift` by `10000000000` the value of `b` is still `0b00`. So, the OR operation will again give the same value.

Comment: Oh! Didn’t see that.